# me.com is coded with javascript+css+html only?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, flash

I wonder if me.com is coded with javascript+css+html only?

No RIA language like Flash, Java right?

Comment: Disable the browser plugins and then reopen the website. In Firefox you can do it from Tools -> Add-ons -> Plugins.

Comment: @Christian: Good idea, I disabled them all and it still worked. So I guess only js+css+html.

Comment: You don't need Flash to build interactive websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me.com is clearly not using Flash , right click anywhere in the browser and you will quickly find out. furthermore, it wouldn't make sense for Apple to get anywhere near Flash.

This article should give you a few answers about Apple's RIA perspective
http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/05/07/apple_developing_flash_alternative_named_gianduia.html

You may also want to have a look at the [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) & [Capuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) frameworks in order to have an idea of where Apple is likely heading.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source of the page, it's only JS, CSS, HTML.

Apple is staying away from Flash / Java and pushing HTML5 as much as they can to promote their i devices.

Comment: So Apple don't believe in Flash and Java? Do they believe in RIA applications though or do they go the web application with HTML5 way?

Comment: Apple is embracing HTML5 totally. A Rich Internet Application does not have to be made from Flash/Silverlight/Java. HTML5 + JavaScript can provide almost the same functionality without the need to install a component.  So Yes, Apple believes in RIA applications, but they will be going with HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. In fact, *contra* PatrickS's comment that [SproutCore](http://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore) might tell us where Apple is "likely" heading, MobileMe is actually built on SproutCore! SproutCore is an HTML + Javascript web application framework whose power is not yet generally appreciated, and derives from its having been engineered to support MobileMe and iWork.com.